# How to calculate a cummulative sum in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I developed my program with C# with Entity Framework and using LINQ for the query. And I have a problem while converting my SQL query to LINQ.

I don't know what to do, please.

Here is my SQL query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT bs.idBalancesortie, bs.datesortie, bs.c_num_debut,bs.c_num_fin,bs.nombredetickets
    , n.quotite, bs.montant
    , SUM(bs.montant) OVER (ORDER BY bs.idNature ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Cumul
    , bs.idNature
FROM BalanceSortie bs
LEFT JOIN Natures n on bs.idNature = n.idNature
order BY bs.idNature
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, So here is the immediate problem, LINQ has nothing to do with Sql or Sql Server. Are you using EF or some sort of ORM, why do you believe linq will help you here ? Do you have models in C# that relate to your data... Just a little bit more of an explanation would go a long way as well as all the points above

Comment: i'm using entity framework to generate the database from the model

Comment: Window Functions in EF ate not implemented. Only via third party extensions.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for cumul reset to zero for each idNature**

I have not tested this solution, but the key to getting a running sum is to create the "cumul" variable and use a multi-statement lambda.   This will require early execution (.ToList() or AsEnumerable()) after the Join.

I added a second variable that holds the "current idNature.   Assumed it to be an int and that it cannot be -1.

```cs
    decimal cumul = 0; // define a variable
    int idNature = -1;
    var target = BalanceSorties
        .Join(idNature, bs => bs.idNature, n => n.idNature, (bs, n) => new { bs, n })
        .OrderBy(q => q.n.idNature)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(q => 
        {
            if (idNature != q.n.idNature)
            {
               cumul =0;
               idNature = q.n.IdNature;
            }
            cumul += q.bs.montant;
            return new
            {
                q.bs.idBalancesortie,
                q.bs.datesortie,
                q.bs.c_num_fin,
                q.bs.nombredetickets,
                q.n.quotité,
                Cumul = cumul,
                q.bs.idNature
            };
        })
    
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing it now

Comment: Let me know if you have a problem?

Comment: Please try now?

Comment: Thank you for your help, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

it calculates the cumulative sum of the "montant" but I want this cumulative sum to be done by "idNature"

For example

```
id Category montant  cumul
1   C         49       49
2   A         4        4
3   A         16      20
```

4

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer. Why did you post this?

Comment: I believe my answer surprised you .. your code works well but it does not solve my problem ..
my objective is to calculate the cumulative sum of "montant" by nature.

thanks again for your precious help!

Comment: I so wish people wouldn't delete comments.

Comment: You should change your original post, because there the cumul is just a running sum of montant.